# Making predictions using Keras. I keep getting error message

Tags: keras, predict

Sorry if the query is primitive. 
I have some code trying to classify integers if they are prime numbers or not. I have trained model using Keras. I am trying make predictions using:

`predict( x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)`

I keep getting the following error message:

> ---->  predict(x=5000003, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
>
> NameError: name 'predict' is not defined

When I used the the following command :"model.predict(x=5000003, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)" I got this error message "AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model'"

Code:

```
import numpy
from numpy import array
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV




seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)



def isPrime(number):
    if number == 1:
        return 0
    elif number == 2:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        return 0
    for d in range(3, int(number**(0.5)+1), 2):
        if number % d == 0:
            return 0
    else:
        return 1


p=[]
N=[]
for i in range (1,10000):
    p=[i,isPrime(i)]
    N=N+[p]

a=array (N)

X=a[:10000,0]
Y=a[:10000,1]



def create_model(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='selu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model



# create model

        model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, init='glorot_uniform', verbose=0)
        kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
        results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold)
        print(results.mean())
        predict(x=5000003, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

`predict` is a function of the `model` object, so you would use it as:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, init='glorot_uniform', verbose=0)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
# Call on model
model.predict(x=5000003, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/4ba641806b4afcf95bece96c3b15e646fc092161/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L212) to investigate what it does behind the scenes.

Comment: when I put the command model.predict(x=5000003, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None), I got the following error message : 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'model'!

Comment: It is a function of the classifier model object you create.